# Android - How to know when getView is called to inflate list

Tags: android, listview, getview

I have a List Adapter which inflates a list. On the method `getView()` i make an `AscyncTask` to get an image from internet. However, i figured out that the method `getView()` is called for numerous reasons, not only to inflate the list.

My question is: how to know when the method is called to inflate the list? I don't want to make a `AsyncTask` every time the method is called.

Here is my code:

```
public class ListItem extends ArrayAdapter<Carro> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final List<Carro> carros;

    public ListItem(Activity context, List<Carro> carros) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, carros);
        this.context = context;
        this.carros = carros;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);

        TextView modelo = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.modelo);
        modelo.setText(carros.get(position).getModelo());

        GetFoto getFoto = new GetFoto(rowView);
        getFoto.execute(position);
        return rowView;
    }

    private class GetFoto extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

        Drawable fotoDraw;
        View rowView;
        int position;

        public GetFoto(View view) {
            this.rowView = view;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            position = params[0];
            HTTPHandler handler = new HTTPHandler();

            fotoDraw = handler.makeServiceCallImage(carros.get(position).getFoto());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            ImageView imagem = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imagem);
            imagem.setImageDrawable(fotoDraw);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder what you mean with 'inflate the list'. Further you could of the numerous reasons mention a few as i only know one reason why getView() is called.

Comment: You should create an async task for every picture you wanna load. And every time getView() wants one. Well if you do not cache the downloaded pictures you have to download them again while scrolling up and down.

Comment: For example, if my adapter has a List with 2 items, the method getView() is called like 8 times. And every time the method is called, it will create a asyncTask, even though the list itself doesn't have 8 items. I want to call the AsyncTask only when the list item will become a row

Answer (score 1):

The method `getView()` will be called every time the view appears on the screen during the scrolling process. The number of `getView()` method calls can be greater than the number of elements if the `ListView` height is set to `wrap_content`.

Use some libraries like `Picasso` or `Glide` for downloading images. These libraries will cache the downloaded images that prevents unnecessary requests.

It will look like this:

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(imageUrl)
     .into(imageView);
```

Or you can read this article https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap.html

I recommend using `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`. It recycling the views which prevents multiple inflation

Answer (score 0):

Like Alex Nik said: use picasso or glide for picture loads.
And stop using ListViews, they are kind of deprecated, yet still supported. Use RecyclerView, it is better and easier to use.